# WPF click event handler get textblock text

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

I have a text block in my xaml:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="InterfacesDataTemplate"
              DataType="ca:Interface">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" 
                   MouseLeftButtonDown="interface_mouseDown"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

On the code behind I have an event handler for click (double-click)

```
private void interface_mouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = sender as TextBox;
    if (e.ClickCount == 2)
        MessageBox.Show("Yeah interfac " + tb.Text);
}
```

I'm getting a NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var tb = sender as TextBox
```

This results in `null` because it's actually a `TextBlock`.

Just change to

```
var tb = sender as TextBlock
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely what `sender` must to be *`TextBlock`*. And for the future you should check the sender on the *`null`* in order once again not raise an exception:

```
var tb = sender as TextBlock;

if (tb != null)
{
    // doing something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it compact and easy just do these changings:

```
private void interface_mouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.ClickCount == 2)
    MessageBox.Show("Yeah interfac " + ((TextBlock)sender).Text);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ohh oops didn't see you were trying to cast as TextBox not TextBlock. Assuming you want TextBlock then look at below:

I don't use code behind events. I try to use commands to do everything. However, one workaround I would immediately try is putting a name on the control and accessing it directly in code behind like so:

```
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" x:Name="MyTextBlock"
           Text="{Binding Path=Name}" MouseLeftButtonDown="interface_mouseDown"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Then can access in back:

```
  private void interface_mouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
    if (MyTextBlock.ClickCount == 2)
        MessageBox.Show("Yeah interfac " + MyTextBlock.Text);
  }
```

Also note, i could be wrong but idk if 'ClickCount' is a nav property on the control TextBlock or TextBox.

Comment: Please post comment for why -1 to case an argument.