# Visual Studio C# hyperlink loads in browser AND in .net app

Tags: c#, .net, hyperlink

I have a VS 2010 .net app with a hyperlink within a textblock within a stackpanel on a .XAML.  When I run the app it opens the link in a new tab in IE which is great, it's exactly what I want.  But it also opens it in the executing app panel.  I can navigate away and back and get back to the page in my app that I was working on but I need to keep it from loading on that page to begin with.  Otherwise the behavior is exactly what I want.  Note: I tried using the AbsoluteUri line that is commented out but that had the same behavior PLUS would shut the app down. Thanks in advance.

````
  <Hyperlink RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate" NavigateUri="http://www.msn.com">Click here to go to msn</Hyperlink></TextBlock>

private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender,           System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
        {
//            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.msn.com");
        } ```
````

Comment: Try to remove `NavigateUri` from xaml.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that was supposed to have the opposite effect, open the page in the app and not in a browser (according to what I've read) BUT I tried that and the link just seems inactive.

Comment: You aren't using `e` in the event handler, so I thought removing URI may do a trick. In another similar question someone suggest to mimic `Hyperlink` by having an ordinal `TextBlock` with click event.

Comment: That is true, now.  But you can see the commented out line in the method and I did but it caused even more problems which just caused the app to quit with no errors or anything.  I'm sorry but I don't understand your suggestion, can you provide a bit of code to help me see what you're talking about?  (I'm a noob)  I don't see a click event for TextBlock

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37429964/1997232) is duplicate I mentioned. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294549/1997232) for click event.